# Google Maps API v3 - custom driving directions markers

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How would I replace the driving directions markers (not the map markers) in google maps api v3?

I haven't seen examples of this anywhere...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes simplicity is key.

I answered my question by using css:

The A line is a table:

```
<table id="adp-placemark" class="adp-placemark" jstcache="0">
```

and B line is:

```
<table class="adp-placemark" jstcache="0">
```

So the following css will change the markers:

```
#adp-placemark img, .adp-placemark img {
   display:none;
}
#adp-placemark {
   font-weight: bold;
   padding: 10px 10px 10px 30px;
   background: white url(../images/map_icons/number_1.png) no-repeat left center;
}
.adp-placemark {
   font-weight: bold;
   padding: 10px 10px 10px 30px;
   background: white url(../images/map_icons/number_2.png) no-repeat left center;
}
```

Comment: This works only for two results.  Any thoughts on how to get this to work for an arbitrary amount of way-points (legs)?

Comment: @DannyC You'd have to set a bunch of legs, get the css of each element, and style each one accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue.  Similar to Jason's solution of using CSS, I used jQuery to manually replace the icon images with my own icon images.  This allows me to use the same icon image in the maps and in the directions.  This also allows me to use click handlers to open the same info window when the marker is clicked in either the map or directions panel.  I use different icons for both the home and end location and use ascending number markers for the waypoints.  The one annoying caveat was that I needed to use a JavaScript timer to wait 1.5 seconds so I could be sure the directions finished rendering since its asynchronous and there is no call back for that.  The images cannot be replaced until they are added to the DOM.
Here is my code:

```
    function renderDrivingDirections(directionsResponse){
    var directionRenderOptions = {
            map: map,
            panel: directionsPanel,
            suppressInfoWindows: true,
            suppressMarkers: true
    };
    var directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(directionRenderOptions);
    directionsRenderer.setDirections(directionsResponse);
    /* Replace the default map markers with custom ones for following reasons:
        1) Control over icon.  (Custom icons for start and finish)
        2) Control over icon color (to match the action status)
        3) Control infowindow that opens on marker click (Add Call/Action, add link to action details)
        However, we using the default rendering for the lines, and for text output of directions. So we need to wait 1.5 seconds after load 
    */
    window.setTimeout(    
            function(){
                showWaypointMarkers(directionsResponse);
                showOriginDestinationMarkers();
            },
            1500
    );
}

function showWaypointMarkers(directionsResponse) {
    var routeLegs = directionsResponse.routes[0].legs;
    var allImages = jQuery(directionsPanel).find("img");
    for (var i = 0, len = routeLegs.length -1; i < len; i++) {
        var iconUrl = "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter_withshadow&chld=" + (i+1) + "|ffffff|000000";
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: routeLegs[i+1].start_location,
            map: map,
            title: "Stop number: " + i,
            icon: {url: iconUrl}
        });
        var iconImageObj = jQuery("<img src='" + iconUrl + "'>");
        attachInfoWindow(marker, iconImageObj, i, routeLegs[i+1]);            
        allImages.eq(i+1).replaceWith(iconImageObj);
    }
}

function attachInfoWindow(marker, iconImageObj, legIndex, leg) {
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "<div><h3>Stop Number: " + legIndex + "</h3><p>" + leg.start_address + "</p><a href='#'>(Stop Details)</a></div>"
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){ //when the marker on map is clicked open info-window
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });
    iconImageObj.click(function(){ //when the marker on the driving directions is clicked, open info-window
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });
}
function showOriginDestinationMarkers(){ //here using same icon for first and last
    var iconUrl = "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_icon_withshadow&chld=home|000000|FFFFFF"; //home icon
    new google.maps.Marker({ //add home location to map
        position: homeLocation,
        map: map, 
        title: messages.homeLocationTitle,
        icon: {url: iconUrl}
    });
    jQuery(directionsPanel, "img").first().replaceWith("<img src='" + iconUrl + "'>"); //replace their icon with ours
    jQuery(directionsPanel, "img").last().replaceWith("<img src='" + iconUrl + "'>"); //replace their icon with ours
}
```

To avoid using a timer I would need to parse the directions and display them myself.  The info windows have custom text based on waypoint and a link to a details page.

Comment: great answer. I looked at doing it this way too, but also ran into the timing issue.

Comment: this is hacky, but it works!  one thing to note, instead of using a set timeout, i used google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() { .... } );

Comment: Not a good idea. Use `suppressMarkers` and the create your own markers with a custom icon wherever you need. The same applies to the other answer.

Comment: `suppressMarkers` only effects the map's directions rendering not the textual directions `panel` that Google Maps provides. There- the html comes directly from Google with no API options to control it. The _proper_ thing to do in this case is to parse the `DirectionsResult` and create your own customized panel. But that's a lot more work.

Comment: +1 Super cool! DirectionsRenderer should support origin and destination icons as parameters. That is just broken and incompatible to have supressMarkers for DirectionsService, but not having a way to couple with it in the DirectionsRenderer.